# The wait operation timed out ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Getting an error when trying to open just one webpage on my site as opposed to the entire thing. The two pages I have been working on are below. They are in place to allow an admin to edit items on the site. Really need help.
Stack Trace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The wait operation timed out.)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6568558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable) +1730
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +219
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6601145
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2102
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1079
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +292
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +420
   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable) +277
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +3326091
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +313
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.PerformSelect() +124
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +146
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView.CreateChildControls() +80
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +189
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +60
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +222
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4297
```

itemediting.aspx:

```
   <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="itemediting.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_itemediting" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>elmtree - Admin</title>      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/mylist.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <img src="images/ELleft.png" style="width:226px; height:52px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 17px; text-align: justify; float: none;"/></a></li>

<div class="container">
    <h1> Item Edit </h1> </div>    
        <div class="container">    
            <div class="form-group">    
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item name: </label>     
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemnametext" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control">    
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ID="updatebutton" role="button" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="updatebutton_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>               
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

itemediting.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;    
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;    

public partial class admin_itemediting : System.Web.UI.Page{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            int row = 0;
            if (Request.QueryString["itemID"] != null)
            {    
                row = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["itemID"]);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("itemedit.aspx");
            }    
        }

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);    
        myConnection.Open();    
        string query = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ID=@rowid";        
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);    
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowid", row);    
        SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string myname = rdr["itemname"].ToString();    
            itemnametext.Text = myname;
        }
    }

    protected void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;    
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);    
        myConnection.Open();    
        string itemnametextupdate = itemnametext.Text;    
        string query = "UPDATE reports SET itemname = @itemnewname";        
        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);     
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemnewname", itemnametextupdate);    
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();    
        myConnection.Close();    
        Response.Redirect("updateimage.aspx");    
    }

    public object row { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap SqlConnection and anything else that implements `IDisposable` interface in a [using block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx), or ensure you dispose it in a finally block.

Comment: any way you could provide some code as a tip? im very new to asp.net + c#. thanks

Comment: Why not read the documentation I linked to in my previous comment?

Comment: i dont really have the time, against the clock here

Comment: So what you're saying is you don't have time to actually learn because you procrastinated your homework until the last minute? Yeah, definitely not going to just give you the code. Read the documentation I provided, it's far more important to understand than having your assignment done right now.

Comment: you have a connection opened on page load, another in update which is opened/closed (which btw is asking for trouble, look up `using`) which is exhausting the connection pool as well.

Answer (score 1):

As @mason mentioned, you have to make sure you call `Dispose()` when you are done with stuff that implement `IDisposable`.

Change you code dealing with `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader`:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ID=@rowid";  

using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection))
{
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowid", row);    
    myConnection.Open();   

    using (SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string myname = rdr["itemname"].ToString();    
            itemnametext.Text = myname;
        }
    }
}
```